# Query with REGEXP without observance of order of words

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, pdo

First of all I want to excuse me for any english mistakes that might be in my texts, in fact it is not my mother language so it's not really perfect... Anyways:
I am using a table for search tags which contains all search tags and a unique name they belong to. For the actual search query, I use REGEXP (the query is written in PDO style). The user has to type in the search keywords seperated with a comma.
As I executed several tests I noticed that the shown results are depending on the order of the typed in words and the order the search tags are stored in the seach tags table.

My question is: How can I execute a query using REGEXP which does ignore the order of the words?

Till now the actual query is pretty simple:

```
$search = explode(',', htmlentities($_POST["search"]));
$search = implode('|', $search);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT name FROM blablabla WHERE name REGEXP :search");
$stmt->bindValue(":search", $search, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not familiar with explode and implode, but the following regex ignores order:  `/(a|b|c)+/`.  It matches at least one occurrence of a, b or c in any order. [Example](http://regex101.com/r/oT7lG7/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sorry, but I do not know, wether this is possible, at least in a performant way.
I would try to achieve it like that:

```
$search = explode(',', htmlentities($_POST["search"]));

$sql = 'SELECT name FROM blablabla ';
$query = array();
$parts = array();

foreach($search as $value) {
    $query[] = 'name LIKE ?';
    $parts[] = '%' . $value . '%';
}

$sql .= ' WHERE ' . implode(' OR ', $query); //Or use logical AND. Just what suits you
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($parts);
```